# hibernate QueryException: could not resolve property in spring petclinic sample application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following JPA method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Collection<Owner> findByPetType(Integer typeID) {
    Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT owner FROM Owner owner left join fetch owner.pets as pet WHERE pet.type_id LIKE :typeID");
    query.setParameter("typeID", typeID + "%");
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

It is throwing the following error message:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: type_id of:  
org.springframework.samples.petclinic.model.Pet [SELECT DISTINCT owner FROM  
org.springframework.samples.petclinic.model.Owner owner left join fetch owner.pets  
as pet WHERE pet.type_id LIKE :typeID];  
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: type_id of:  
org.springframework.samples.petclinic.model.Pet [SELECT DISTINCT owner FROM      
org.springframework.samples.petclinic.model.Owner owner left join fetch owner.pets  
as pet WHERE pet.type_id LIKE :typeID]
```

This is from the Spring petclinic sample application, so all relevant code [is at this link](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-petclinic/), including the database definition.  I am using the hsqldb and jpa, the findByPetType() method above is something I wrote, which is not in the sample application.

Can anyone show me how to fix the code so that it does not produce this error message?

EDIT:

I followed Alex's advice and changed pet.type_id to pet.type.  Now it is giving me the following error message (the value of typeID is set to 1):

```
Parameter value [1%] did not match expected type  
[org.springframework.samples.petclinic.model.PetType]; nested exception is  
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1%] did not match expected type  
[org.springframework.samples.petclinic.model.PetType]
```

SECOND EDIT:

I made Sergi Almar's suggestion, and now it is throwing the following error:

```
Parameter value [1%] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer]; nested exception   
is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1%] did not match expected type   
[java.lang.Integer]
```

I checked, and the calling code initiates typeID as "Integer typeID = 1;"  So I am not sure why it is not seeing an integer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this is a JPQL query, you should use the entity properties in the query (Pet has a PetType which has an id). The following code will do what you expect:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Collection<Owner> findByPetType(Integer typeID) {
     Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT owner FROM Owner owner left join fetch owner.pets as pet WHERE pet.type.id = :typeID");
    query.setParameter("typeID", typeID);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  +1 for trying to help.  I posted the results of trying your suggestion in the second edit to my original posting above.  Can you tell me how to get past the new error message?

Comment: Copy the code I posted, I've tested it myself and it works. Notice that you need to defined the id in the query (pet.type.id) not the type object. Also remove the % when setting the parameter

Comment: Yes, removing the % was the issue.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Change `pet.type_id` to `pet.type`. You have to use entity's mapping properties (but not column names) in `HQL`.

Comment: Thank you.  +1 for trying to help.  I put an edit to my original posting above with the result of trying your suggestion.  typeID is an Integer, being passed in as the value 1.  Do you have a way to fix the new error message which resulted from trying your suggestion?